# How to update API Name of a Custom Label

Tags: salesforce, sfdc

Need to update "API Name" of Custom Label but "**Name**" field of Custom Label is **Read only** on Edit!

There are too many Labels to be updated, Do I need to recreate all and delete earlier?

is there any way to modify/update API Name of a Custom Label ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if you want to rename API names of these labels you need to delete and recreate them with correct names.

Comment: but it isn't feasible, is there any other way?

Comment: @SachinHandibag unfortunately, not